# PHP static property behavior

Tags: php, oop, static, abstract

I'm trying to understand static property behavior in an abstract class.this is an example code retrieved from *php object patterns and practice* book (chapter 11-decorative pattern) :

```
abstract class Expression {

   private static $keycount=0;

   private $key;

   function getKey() {
    if ( ! isset( $this->key ) ) {
        self::$keycount++;
        $this->key=self::$keycount;
      }

    return $this->key;
   }
}
```

a number of sub classes are extended from this abstract class and then `getKey()` method will be called at instantiating time.each one check its own `$key` property and if its null ,then increase `$keycount` by one and assign it to `$key` property .
as i understand `$keycount` save its last value regardless of which subclass its running on . i mean it is in the context of abstract class NOT the context of sub classes. if it was dependent to its subclass then it would be reset to `0` in each subclass.can anyone provide me more insight into this ?

Comment: If you want it as a count of each subclass, then define `protected static $keycount=0;` and `protected $key;` in each subclass where you want an individual count, and change `self::$keycount++; $this->key=self::$keycount;` to `static::$keycount++; $this->key=static::$keycount;`

Comment: Remember that there is only one instance of the `Expression::$keycount` variable. That is what `static` implies. It is available to __any instance of `Expression`_. So, whenever the `getKey()` method, is called  from any instance,  then it may update the, one and only, `Expression::$keycount` variable. Note:  Each instance has its own $key local variable.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks. your comment might be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you answer your own question.

> as i understand $keycount save its last value regardless of which subclass its running on

Yes, it works this way. The `$keycount` is shared between all subclasses.
Here is a simple test to check this behavior:

```
<?php
abstract class Expression {

   private static $keycount=0;

   private $key;

   function getKey() {
    if ( ! isset( $this->key ) ) {
        self::$keycount++;
        $this->key=self::$keycount;
      }

    return $this->key;
   }
}

class ChildOne extends Expression {
}

class ChildTwo extends Expression {
}

$one = new ChildOne();
print 'One get key: ' . $one->getKey().PHP_EOL;
print 'One get key: ' . $one->getKey().PHP_EOL;
$oneMore = new ChildOne();
print 'One more get key: ' . $oneMore->getKey().PHP_EOL;
print 'One more get key: ' . $oneMore->getKey().PHP_EOL;
$two = new ChildTwo();
print 'Two get key: ' . $two->getKey().PHP_EOL;
print 'Two get key: ' . $two->getKey().PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
One get key: 1
One get key: 1
One more get key: 2
One more get key: 2
Two get key: 3
Two get key: 3
```